# Find EditText that have focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, onfocus

I have 12 EditText fields and several buttons on a form. On the first EditText the user have to enter a Area code and the next a phone number. I want to be able to stop the user and set focus back to the EditText if the number of digits are incorrect.
I have OnFocusChangeListner on the area code but the focus stays on the EditText the user have touch.

```
 cArea.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                if (cArea.getText().toString().length() < 3) {
                    cArea.requestFocus();
                }
            }
            else  getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

I tried to ad this to the activity:

```
public class EnterInfo extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener, View.OnFocusChangeListener

View myView = findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
myView.setOnFocusChangeListener(EnterInfo.this);
```

mainlayout is the top layout that holds all other layouts.
And the following to clear the focus. But it never get called.

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){

        if(v.getId()!= cArea.getId()){
            EditText MyEdit= (EditText) findViewById(((EditText) v).getId());
            MyEdit.clearFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

And if I can get it to work is there away to check what have the focus (EditText, Button, etc..) so I don't cast MyEdit to a Button as EditText.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone|textNoSuggestions"
        android:id="@+id/cArea"
        style="@style/BlackSText"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="@string/area"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cPhone"
        style="@style/BlackSText"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|top"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|number"
        android:maxLength="7"
        android:minWidth="120dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="@string/phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cLName"
        style="@style/BlackSText"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textCapWords|textPersonName"
        android:minWidth="400dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:maxLength="30"
        android:hint="@string/lname" />            

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textCapWords|textPersonName"
        android:id="@+id/cFName"
        android:gravity="start"
        style="@style/BlackSText"
        android:hint="@string/fname"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cEmail"
        style="@style/BlackSText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textEmailAddress"
        android:minWidth="300dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clearBtn"
        style="@style/BlackText"
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:background="@drawable/orangebtn"
        android:text="@string/clear"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|bottom|top" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cStreet"
        style="@style/BlackSText"
        android:layout_width="450dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="@string/street"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textCapWords|textPostalAddress"
        android:maxLength="30"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cCity"
        style="@style/BlackSText"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textCapWords"
        android:hint="@string/city"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cState"
        style="@style/BlackSText"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textNoSuggestions"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cZip"
        style="@style/BlackSText"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|number"
        android:hint="@string/zip"
        android:maxLength="5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <EditText
        style="@style/BlackSText"
        android:id="@+id/apartmentEd"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:hint="@string/apartment"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <EditText
        style="@style/BlackSText"
        android:id="@+id/buildingEd"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:hint="@string/building"
        android:maxLength="5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|number"
        android:id="@+id/cMobile"
        style="@style/BlackSText"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:hint="@string/mobile"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you provide xml layout so it helps anyone who wants to try it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this bellow code :

```
    cArea.setOnFocusChangeListener(EnterInfo.this);
    phnNumber.setOnFocusChangeListener(EnterInfo.this);

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){

            if(v.getId()== cArea.getId()){
               cArea.clearFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I check when the cArea lose focus and if the length is not 3 digit I want the focus to go back to cArea but to do that I have to cancel the focus on the EditText that the user have touched. I will have the same problem when the cPhone and the cName that are the minimum requirement for addig the person to the database. Since there is 14 EditText boxes. Could I make a Loop and cancel the focus on all and then in the end set the focus to the cArea?

Comment: You can also fix the edittext length or set error to the edit text

Comment: I tried to make the loop that didn't work. I made the loop to cancel focus on all TextEdit and then set the requestFocus on the cArea, but it still had the view on the TextView the user had click plus on the cArea the cursor was flipping constantly between the two TextEdit's. I ended up just checking the TextEdit and if it is wrong let the user know and then the user have to touch the EditText to correct.